# Polymer firebase-document data becomes bound to multiple paths

Tags: firebase, data-binding, firebase-realtime-database, polymer

I have an application that uses firebase-document to access data based on a given unit ID, like so:

```
<firebase-document
    app-name="acw"
    path="/units/statuses/[[unitId]]"
    data="{{unitData}}"
    id="unitdata[[unitId]]">
</firebase-document>
```

The component which contains the firebase-document is reached from an inventory page that has links for multiple units, and the unitId is sent in as an attribute from the parent component. This works fine if I only access one unit in a given session.

Here's the problem: If I'm viewing data for unit A, and then go back to the inventory page and select unit B, my bound variable "unitData" will respond to changes from BOTH paths. I.e., the on-screen data will literally flicker between unit-A data and unit-B data as updates get pushed to those paths in my firebase. (I have a process running on a separate server that updates all unit data every minute, so the wonky binding issue is a big problem. I can reproduce the effect by updating the units manually through the firebase console.)

NOTE: When this problem occurs, the URI remains correct, as does the unitId. It's only the data attribute of the firebase-document element that seems confused. So my question is, how is this happening, and how can I ensure that firebase-document is bound to only one path?

Other details:
- Using Polymer version 0.17.0 (is an upgrade my best hope?)

Comment: 0.17.0 version? how? did you mean 1.7.0 ?. nevermind, upgrading polymer won't help. I have one idea. Do you define property of some element with empty array as default value? like: `testProperty: {value: []}`.
If so, then change it to `testProperty: {value: function(){return []}}`.  Without any code specified it is hard to recognise what is going on in your application